My system is complaining about HPE repository not being signed
In short, I would like to add an HPE repository on my Debian 12 system. I added the repository into it's own list in sources.list.d, instead of directly onto sources.list, as I have heard that is bad practice. Every time I update, I get these messages:

GPG error: http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp bookworm/current Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C208ADDE26C2B797
E: The repository 'http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp bookworm/current Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I checked, and the gpg keys are in the repository, and all I find when researching are .pub keys instead of .gpg keys.
EDIT: Yes during my initial research I have found this debian forum but was of the understanding the apt-key command has been depreciated, so I payed it no mind. However, if it is okay to use apt-key in this case, then I will use that instead. Sorry for the mix-up.
EDIT2: So I changed my source file, mcp.list, to reflect this: deb http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/debian/ bookworm/12.80 non-free non-free-firmware
Afterwards I ran these commands:

curl -fsSL https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey2048.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hpPublicKey2048.gpg
curl -fsSL https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpePublicKey2048_key1.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hpePublicKey2048_key1.gpg
curl -fsSL https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey2048_key1.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/hpPublicKey2048_key1.gpg

Except I nothing still worked, then I experimented with the directory and changed to the the directory of trusted.gpg.d. Now THIS ended up making a bigger difference. Now it is half-way working, with some of the repository being ignored:

Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free-firmware/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/debian bookworm/12.80 InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free-firmware' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free-firmware/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/debian bookworm/12.80 InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free-firmware' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
Skipping acquire of configured file 'non-free-firmware/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/debian bookworm/12.80 InRelease' doesn't have the component 'non-free-firmware' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

I then went to experiment on this some more by changing my source file to reflect the changes it suggested: "InRelease," "Release," etc. However I am still getting a similar result, whenever I change the the file to reflect these, it pops up a similar message but with another word I am apparently missing.

What research have you done? When I search for the error message, and the public key signature, I was able to find a solution to that message

I went on that site, but I noticed that they used the apt key command, so I thought this solution was depreciated. They used the command gpg --armor --export DC30D7C23CBBABEE | sudo apt-key add -, which lead me to think this was. I thought here on super user, someone would have an updated solution.

Did you try the solution?

Here are instructions from September 2023

This can be explained as downloading and then importing the key from the source. Here is the correct key.

I have figured out what went wrong in the source after its edit, which was a typo, while it did ask me to get rid of the section "non-free-firmware" and it asked me to rid the word "InRelease," however, after trying again it finally worked, The end result is:

deb http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/mcp/debian/ bookworm/12.80 non-free

I do not know why it took me two tried of omitting "non-free-firrmware" and getting a different result each time, but continuing on.
Afterwards, using Matt's updated answer here I had to make a few changes, and it works. Essentially change the directory to keyrings to trusted.gpg.d.

curl -fsSL https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey2048.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/hpPublicKey2048.gpg


curl -fsSL https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpePublicKey2048_key1.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/hpePublicKey2048_key1.gpg


curl -fsSL https://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/hpPublicKey2048_key1.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/hpPublicKey2048_key1.gpg

Afterwards, update and it seemed to work for me. I am not sure if it is practical, as I am still new to linux, but this is what worked for me, and hopefully helps others.
